# matlab: use of multiple hashmaps

Tags: matlab, hashmap

Is there a possibility in matlab to create a list of hashmaps.

I have the following problem:

```
A1          A2                A3
alphas      alphas2           alphas3
radius      radius2           radius3
SV          SV2               SV3
```

Therefore I need a map containing A1, A2, A2 and for each index, for example A1, I have to be able to access to the different values of A1, so alphas, radius, SV.

Comment: Can you use a structure? You could define fields `A1.alpha`, `A1.radius` etc

Comment: or you can make use of cells if you know in what sequence A's are occuring

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks like an array of structs, which is initialized as follows:

```
map(1).A = 'So long';
map(1).alphas = [];
map(1).radius = [];
map(1).SV = [];

map(2).A = 'farewell';
map(2).alphas = [];
map(2).radius = [];
map(2).SV = [];

map(3).A = 'auf wiedersehen, goodbye!';
map(3).alphas = [];
map(3).radius = [];
map(3).SV = [];
```

Bonus: You can now easily iterate over map as follows:

```
for item = map
    disp(item.A)
end
```

BR Magnus